# Ngrx Store, Effects, Http Ajax Polling Setup on Angular 2

Tags: angular, ngrx, ajax-polling, ngrx-effects

I'm creating an Ngrx Angular 2 app and was trying to get my http calls to continue polling after a time interval. I have seen the use of the `interval()` function, but in case of Ngrx, when service calls are done inside `@Effect()`, it gives an error. Please advise:

```
@Injectable()
export class TasksEffects {
constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private TS: TaskService
){}

@Effect()
onLoadTasksLoadTasks$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.ofType(tasksActions.ActionTypes.LOAD_TASKS)
    .switchMap(() => {
        return this.TS.index()
            .map((res) => new tasksActions.LoadTasksSuccessAction(res.json()))
            .catch(err => of(new tasksActions.LoadTasksFailAction(err)));
    });
```

I want to run the switchMap function every ten seconds. This does not work.

```
    @Effect()
onLoadTasksLoadTasks$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.ofType(tasksActions.ActionTypes.LOAD_TASKS)
    .switchMap(() => {
        return this.TS.index()
            .map((res) => new tasksActions.LoadTasksSuccessAction(res.json()))
            .catch(err => of(new tasksActions.LoadTasksFailAction(err)));
    }).interval(10000);
```

The type error is:

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As stated in the other answer, [`interval`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-interval) is a static function, so it does not exist on the `Observable` prototype - which is why your error is effected.

Instead, you should be able to achieve what you want using [`timer`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-timer).

```ts
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/timer';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

@Effect()
onLoadTasksLoadTasks$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
  .ofType(tasksActions.ActionTypes.LOAD_TASKS)
  .switchMap(() => Observable
    .timer(0, 10000)
    .switchMap(() => this.TS.index()
      .map((res) => new tasksActions.LoadTasksSuccessAction(res.json()))
      .catch(err => Observable.of(new tasksActions.LoadTasksFailAction(err)))
    )
  );
```

With `timer`, it's possible to specify an initial delay and here it's set to zero so that the timer fires immediately. After that, it will fire every ten seconds, but if another `LOAD_TASKS` action is received, the `switchMap` will see it unsubscribed and a new `timer` created, etc.

Comment: What stops or unsubscribes  the Observable.timer? Wouldn't this just continue on forever even after receiving the data that was needed?

Comment: Nothing stops it. The OP wanted polling.

Comment: how would I do this with an action payload and rxjs 6? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52263977/how-to-do-http-polling-in-ngrx-effect?noredirect=1#comment91477694_52263977

Answer (score 0):

In rxjs 5 [`interval()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-interval) is a static function. You can only use it as a creator `Observable.interval(1)`.

Try this.

```
this.actions$.ofType(tasksActions.ActionTypes.LOAD_TASKS)
  .skipUntil(Observable.interval(10000))
  .switchMap(res => {...})
```