# How to do http polling in ngrx effect

Tags: angular, http, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have this effect, and I'm trying to use timer to poll for data every x seconds. But I can't figure out how timer is supposed to interact with the data streams. I tried adding another switchMap to the top, but then I couldn't pass the action and payload to the second switchmap. Any ideas?

I looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43154461/ngrx-store-effects-http-ajax-polling-setup-on-angular-2) but my situation is a little different. I'm passing a payload with my action that I need to access, and I'm using ngrx 6.

```
@Effect()
getData = this.actions$
    .ofType(appActions.GET_PLOT_DATA)
    .pipe(
        switchMap((action$: appActions.GetPlotDataAction) => {
            return this.http.post(
                `http://${this.url}/data`,
                action$.payload.getJson(),
                {responseType: 'json', observe: 'body', headers: this.headers});
        }),
        map((plotData) => {
            return {
                type: appActions.LOAD_DATA_SUCCESS,
                payload: plotData
            }
        }),
        catchError((error) => throwError(error))
    )
```

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43154461/ngrx-store-effects-http-ajax-polling-setup-on-angular-2

Comment: thanks, I have looked at that one, I'm using RXJS 6 though, and my action has a payload. So I haven't quite been able to get it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work (i have tested it). Please add this top of the `switchMap`. The key operator here is the `mapTo`. This operator will map the incoming value of the interval into the payload.

```
switchMap((action$: appActions.GetPlotDataAction) =>
   interval(5000).pipe(mapTo(action$))
);
```

**Update (hint):**
If you want to start immediately with the polling and then each {n}ms you can use the `startWith` operator or the `timer` observable

```
switchMap((action$: appActions.GetPlotDataAction) =>
  interval(5000).pipe(startWith(0), mapTo(action$))
);
```

or

```
switchMap((action$: appActions.GetPlotDataAction) => 
  timer(0, 1000).pipe(mapTo(action$))
);
```

**Update (15.04.2021):**

For example with takeUntil and a Subject you can stop the polling stream at a time, somewhere in the code like this. You can also kill when someone click on something. It is up to you and use case depending.

```
const kill$ = new Subject();
switchMap((action$: appActions.GetPlotDataAction) => 
  timer(0, 1000).pipe(mapTo(action$), takeUntil(kill$))
);

// killing for example after 60 seconds
setTimeout(() => kill$.next(), 60000);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! thanks. I havent used the mapTo operator, really useful. And I guess I was confusing timer and interval. thanks @Bitcollage!

Comment: @FussinHussin glad to hear.

Comment: thanks for the update, I was just about to say the first call is affected but it's fixed with the second implementation

Comment: one more issue, it makes a call right as the app starts, before the action is submitted. So I get an error right at the beginning. Can I make it wait for the action?

Comment: yes sure, please add as first argument into the pipe `skip(1)`: `interval(5000).pipe(skip(1), mapTo(action$)))`. skip(1) will skip first call.

Comment: and how to stop the interval?

Comment: @Marek I have updated your answer to include your question as an answer.

Comment: For stopping, this would also work: return interval(intervalTime).pipe(
  concatMap(() => this.someService.getSomething()),
  first(
    (someData) =>
      someData.finished
  ),
);