# Polling Effects Ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx, polling, ngrx-effects

I'm new to Ngrx and am having issues setting up polling with Ngrx effects

I've tried the answer mentioned [How to do http polling in ngrx effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52263977/how-to-do-http-polling-in-ngrx-effect) but this does not seem to be working as expected for my solution. I have a feeling that this could be because of my return statement

```
 LoadProcessesByUser$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
   ofType(AppActions.LoadProcessesByUser),
   switchMap(() => {
     interval(100).pipe(
       startWith(0),
       mapTo(this.actions$)
     );
     return this.apiService.getUserProcesses(this.userService.user.lanId).pipe(
       map(result => new LoadProcessesSuccess(result)),
       catchError(error => of(new LoadFailure(error)))
     );
   })
 );
```

I expected to see this effect being called every 100 ms but as it seems, it's only called whenever I dispatch LoadProcessByUser()

Do note; i want this polling to be running for the life of the application.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything with the `interval`, you will have to return the interval and add the service call inside the `interval`s `pipe`.

If you don't need `LoadProcessesByUser` you can also create a stream based on the `interval`, for example

```
@Effect() 
ping = interval(1000).pipe(mapTo(new Ping()));
```

You can find more at [Start using ngrx/effects for this](https://timdeschryver.dev/posts/start-using-ngrx-effects-for-this)

Comment: Awesome! appreciate the insight. Gave the link a read, still new not entirely sure how Ping() fits into that.

Comment: instead of `Ping` you can call your service